# Email - Edit Custom 'opencounter' Layout

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, email-template

How can I modify the layout in:

```
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
```

I'm trying to create a fluid email layout. When the screen size is adjusted for mobile viewing the exact target logo and some of the links and text are not fluid.

If I can adjust the snippet inside this custom tag that would be very helpful. If I cannot have access to it, is there a way to adjust the layout of the tracker another way?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

That HTML tag is a 1x1 empty pixel that tracks a Subscriber's open, it has no relation to the layout of the email. Headers and Footers are configured in the ExactTarget account separately.

Comment: How does one go about editing the Header and Footer?  Is there some process?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than Admin -> Send Management -> Delivery Profiles -> (within a profile) -> Library Content?

Comment: There is no Admin->Send Management... that i have access to. I see tracking configuration -> custom tab but there is nothing listed to 'edit'.